# Is there a way to correctly align faces?

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

I am currently using opencv implementation of fisherface, and I read somewhere that it is possible to get very good results if we have good face alignment.

Is there a best way of doing that? Because anatomy of people is different from person to person. So for example, if I use the eye to align the faces, I may have trouble with the mouth.

Comment: This is something I would like to know also

Comment: You might want to take a look to this [answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/24670/how-can-i-align-face-images/?answer=24845#post-id-24845). He is using eyes to align faces but it seems to give good results.

Answer (score 0):

Face alignment can be handled if you know the locations of eyes. We expect that the both eyes should be horizontal. deepface offers an out-of-the-box function to apply face detection and alignment. It wraps opencv haar cascade, single shot multibox detector, dlib hog or mtcnn as face detectors.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
backend = 'opencv' #opencv, ssd, dlib or mtcnn
img = DeepFace.detectFace("img.jpg", detector_backend = backend)
plt.imshow(img); plt.show()
```